# filtrar ultimos registros

Tags: html5, json, css3, angularjs-2.0

Buenas, estoy un poco perdido con esto ya que no controlo **Angular Material**.

He creado una tabla en la que me aparecen todos los resultados que tengo actualmente en el **JSON** y tengo que hacer una función en la que haga un filtro para mostrar los últimos *X* registros, en el que *X* es el número que yo introduzco a mostrar.

HTML

```
<list-account-movements layout="row" flex="100" filtro-selecionado="vm.filterSelected" filter-value="vm.Ultimos registros" layout-wrap></list-account-movements>
```

Este es el campo del formulario

```
<input type="number" class="input2 inputPresonalizado2" ng-model="vm.lastMovement" maxlength="3"/>
```

y en el **JS** he introducido el binding en el controller

```
bindings: {
   filtroSelecionado: '<',
   filterValue: '<'
 }
```

y me gustaría saber si al crear la función de **Angular** como recojo el dato del input para pasar la variable correspondiente para mostrar los últimos registros seleccionados. Por ejempo, si tengo 25 registros y yo pongo para mostrar los últimos 5 registros recoger el value para realizar la búsqueda correspondiente para mostrarlos.

Muchas gracias, un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo hago es tener un objeto en el controlador y asignar el valor del imput al objeto.

```
          $scope.input = {};
```

y en el html haces esto...

```
          <input type="number" class="input2 inputPresonalizado2" ng-model="input.numero" maxlength="3"/>
```

Con esto, al querer obtener el valor del input en el controlador, en este caso lo mostramos en consola, solo haces lo siguiente....

```
          console.log($scope.input.numero);
```

Comment: Al estar programando en **Angular Material** no debería pasar el valor del filtro seleccionado en lo que tengo puesto en la etiqueta "list-account-movements" en el filter-value con el ng-model del input "filter-value="vm.lastMovement" ng-model="vm.lastMovement"?? No sé, esque me suena algo de eso, pero no estoy seguro. Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo que preguntas es como recoger el valor del input... "como recojo el dato del input para pasar la variable correspondiente para mostrar los últimos registros seleccionados".

Comment: sí, es eso, pero con el poco conocimiento que tengo de Angular Material y lo que estoy viendo ya no se utiliza en $scope y he puesto en el input el objeto _ng-model="vm.lastMovement"_  de una modal declarandola en el js correspondiente con el bindings y también he introducido un filter-value para para recoger el valor que se ha introducido en el input, pero en el _alert_ que pongo en la función siempre me pasa en valor vacio aunque esté metiendo algo en el input

Comment: ya conseguí hacerlo, en vez de declarar la variable en el JS como _$scope.nombreVariable= {};_ la declaré como _vm.nombreVariable= {};_ la cual tengo puesta en el _ng.modal_ del input y aparte de eso también se me olvidó declarar la funcion en el _bindings_ para que recoja los datos del value